# How to use count result in Pivot Table in a new field?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

version: Excel 2010

In Pivot Table, how to use the count result for a calculation in the "Insert Calculated Field".

I am trying to calculate the percentage of retrieved counts in respect to the amount sent. However, the amount sent is count of date. Using "Insert Calculated Field", how can I add a field with such result?

```
=count of date/count of retrieved
```

Below is what I have tried and failed. The results in column E are correct but are calculated manually.

[image]

Data

[image]

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you share few lines of data so that we can replicate your problem and try and help your problem.

Comment: @MohitBansal I have added an additional image as per requested. Thank you very much for the advice and attention.